# regex matching the pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Is there a way to write a regular expression in python that matches the string of the following format:

`feat(fix-validation): some texts (Aerogear-G1010)`

or

`feat$($fix-validation$)$:$some texts$($Aerogear-G1010$)`

here, $ = represents Zero or more white space can be present

### breakdown:

`feat` : string from a fixed subset of strings ['feat','fix','docs','breaking']

`fix-validation` : string of max **n** length

`some texts` : string of max **m** length

`Aerogear-G1010` : Prefix should always be a string `Aerogear-` and after that some alphanumeric characters of max **q** length

**Note :** we can't escape the special characters like `(` `)` `:` `-` and should be in the exact same format as shown in the example below:

1. feat(feat-new): new feature for group creation (Aerogear-1234)
2. docs(new docs): add new document on the file repo (Aerogear-G1235)
3. fix(fix-warnings): fix user raised concerns (Aerogear-P1230)

I was only able to match the string with fix subset of strings using pattern: `'^fix|docs|feat\s+\('` . I am not able to add zero or more spaces after a matched string followed by `(some texts) :`

Can this be achieved ? thank you in advance :)

Comment: Yes, it can be achieved.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: You should update your question to show what you have tried so far. Your example is not consistent with your breakdown, `q` is not fixed.

Comment: @0x5453 I was only able to match the first pattern of matching a string with fix subset of string: '^fix|docs|feat\s+. Other than that,, not much progress so far :(

Comment: @Alex thanks.. i will update my progress which I have made so far in the question section

Comment: @Alex, I have made some edits to the question.. Will this help ?

Comment: @Alex thank you so much . I will follow the  references from your answer section to understand the regex you answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your regex, `'^fix|docs|feat\s+\('`, the `\s+` matches any whitespace character between one and unlimited times. This requires at least one whitespace character.

Instead:

```
^(feat|docs|fix|breaking) *\( *(.*?) *\) *: *(.*?) *\( *(.*?) *\)$
```

I have used typed spaces ( ) but if you want to include any space character you should use `\s` which is equivalent to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`.

---

Should do what you are looking for, you can see what each part is doing here: https://regex101.com/r/EsF8FF/4

I'd recommend reading the explanation there and reading the python docs for the `re` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html